# SQL script took too much time and throws a time out error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am executing SQL script from my application. Using this script I am taking data from Product table and putting it into Table1. If I execute this script directly from SSMS it will take 00:01:27 minute. But using application it gives me an error: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Here is my script:

```
-- Deleting [Table1] table if exists before creating because we don't need to keep track of records
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Table1'))
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[Table1]
END

-- Creating [Table1] table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] 
(
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MyStatus] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [InTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [StoreId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LanguageId] [int] NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY([Id])
);

DECLARE @pId int
DECLARE @sId int

Truncate Table [dbo].[Table1]

Insert Into [dbo].[Table1] (ProductId, MyStatus, IsDeleted, InTime, StoreId, LanguageId)
   select distinct 
       p.Id, 1, 1, GETDATE(), s.Id, l.Id 
   from 
       [dbo].[Store] s, [dbo].[Product] p, [dbo].[Language] as l
   left join 
       [dbo].[StoreMapping] sm on sm.EntityId = l.Id 
   where 
       (l.LimitedToStores = 1 and s.Id in (sm.StoreId) 
        and sm.EntityName = 'Language') or l.LimitedToStores = 0 

DECLARE tempCursor CURSOR SCROLL FOR 
   select 
       p.Id, sm.StoreId 
   from 
       [dbo].[Product] as p
   join 
       [dbo].[StoreMapping] as sm on p.Id = sm.EntityId
   join 
       [dbo].[Store] as s on sm.StoreId=s.Id
   where 
       p.LimitedToStores = 1 and sm.EntityName = 'Product'

OPEN tempCursor 
FETCH FIRST FROM tempCursor INTO @pId, @sId

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0   
BEGIN    
    UPDATE [dbo].[Table1] 
    SET IsDeleted = 0
    WHERE ProductId = @pId AND StoreId = @sId

    FETCH NEXT FROM tempCursor INTO @pId, @sId;
END

CLOSE tempCursor

UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET IsDeleted = 0
where ProductId in (Select p.Id 
                    from [dbo].[Product] as p 
                    where p.LimitedToStores = 0)

UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]
SET IsDeleted = 1
where ProductId in (Select p.Id 
                    from [dbo].[Product] as p 
                    where p.Published = 0 OR p.Deleted = 1 
                       OR p.VisibleIndividually = 0)

DEALLOCATE tempCursor
```

Can anyone help me to improve this script?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged. And you should **most definitely** not starting **mixing** those styles! Adopt the proper ANSI JOIN syntax and use it everywhere - beginning right now.

Comment: @marc_s Extremely bad habit to kick: Using loops in SQL instead of writing one single statement ....

Comment: @SQLPolice: couldn't agree more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part with the CURSOR and looping through it to set `IsDeleted=0` in Table1 can be replaced with the following update statement:

```
UPDATE
  [dbo].[Table1]
SET
  IsDeleted=0
FROM
  [dbo].[Product] AS p
  JOIN [dbo].[StoreMapping] AS sm ON p.Id=sm.EntityId
  JOIN [dbo].[Store] AS s ON sm.StoreId=s.Id
  JOIN [dbo].[Table1] AS t1 ON t1.ProductId=p.Id AND t1.StoreId=s.Id
WHERE
  p.LimitedToStores=1 AND
  sm.EntityName ='Product'
```

The last two queries are better written with JOINs

```
UPDATE
  [dbo].[Table1]
SET
  IsDeleted=0
FROM
  [dbo].[Table1] AS t1
  JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS p ON
    p.Id=t1.ProductId
WHERE
  p.LimitedToStores=0

UPDATE
  [dbo].[Table1]
SET
  IsDeleted=1
FROM
  [dbo].[Table1] AS t1
  JOIN [dbo].[Product] AS p ON
    p.Id=t1.ProductId
WHERE
  p.Published=0 OR 
  p.Deleted=1 OR 
  p.VisibleIndividually=0
```

Comment: Good solution. General note @Ankita: In SQL Server, you can very often avoid loops and write them as one single statement. Loops come from "procedural thinking"; however, SQL is "set oriented". Always try to see your solution as one set of data which you want to work upon with one statement.

Comment: What @SQLPolice sais is very true, maybe I should have said that explicitely.

Comment: @TT :  I am having millions of data in Product table, using your queries I am still getting the same error. Please suggest.

Comment: @Ankita How long does the script take now in SSMS? If it takes say 1 minute now, can you increase the timeout on the application side? If you cannot increase you will probably have to analyze the query in SSMS to see what is causing your query to be too slow for you. You can do this by clicking "Include Actual Execution Plan" from the UI of SSMS. You will see an extra tab appear: Execution Plan. SSMS sometimes displays "missing indices" that may help speed up the script.

Comment: @Ankita If you can't get your query to run faster, I would try and find out a way to increase the timeout of running SQL. SQL Server does not time out the query, the application that is running the query is. Eg if you are running from JAVA you would have to increase the transaction timeout (UserTransaction.setTransactionTimeout).

Comment: I am using dot net MVC application. Moreover, transaction timeout of what? SQL SSMS?

Comment: @Ankita Your application executing the script gives you a timeout. This could be a timeout on executing the query, or a timeout of the transaction in which the query is running. You didn't specify the setup exactly, but say you are running the query standalone: you would have to increase the timeout value of your query. I don't know the .NET evironment very well but maybe by setting a larger value by [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I'm seeing the default timeout is only 30 seconds.